# colorization image with specification - python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to color the image in black and white. I do this with this code in python :

```
from PIL import Image

col = Image.open("imgForTest.png")
gray = col.convert('L')
bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<200 else 255, '1')
bw.save("result.png")
```

But I found a problem with the table headers, how can I change the color in the header automatically from black to white.

here is my input and output:

[imgForTest.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHzCW.png)

[result.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCs3u.png)

thank you

Comment: And what about the text color inside table header ?

Comment: the text color inside table header is always white

Comment: But if you convert the table header to white and text color also remains white, then it wont be visible,

Comment: yes, you are right. I want the text color black and the table header to white.